# Copy/Insert copied cells to top of page breaks - I need correct syntax, please

Tags: excel

This is what I have, but it's wrong on two counts - syntax and the insert will need to be changed(maybe).

```
r = 47
Workbooks("TestResults.xls").Activate
    Range("A1:F3").Select
    Selection.Copy
Do Until IsEmpty(ActiveCell.Value)
If Range("A" & r + 1:"A" & r + 2).Value <> "" Then Range("A" & r + 1:"A" & r + 4).Select
Range("A" & r + 1:"A" & r + 4).InsertCopiedCells shift:=xlDown
r = r + 47
Range("A" & r + 1:"A" & r + 2).Select
Loop
```

These lines are my troubles:

```
    If Range("A" & r + 1:"A" & r + 2).Value <> "" Then Range("A" & r + 1:"A" & r + 3).Select
    Range("A" & r + 1:"A" & r + 3).InsertCopiedCells
```

Unless there's an easier way to copy the first three rows of the sheet and insert to the top of each following page break.

Any help?

Well for some strange reason "We are no longer accepting answers from this account."

Here it is anyway:

```
r = 47
    Range("A1").Select
Do Until IsEmpty(ActiveCell.Value)
    Range("A1:F3").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Range("A" & r + 1 & ":" & "A" & r + 4).EntireRow.Insert shift:=xlDown
    r = r + 47
    If Range("A" & r).Value = "" And Range("A" & r + 1).Value = "" Then Range("A" & r + 1).Select
Loop
```

Answer (score 0):

An easier way may be to incorporate the rows into a page header, ie Page Layout > Page Setup, Print Titles and in Rows to repeat at top: put `$1:$3`.